# Magento 2.3.1 modals-wrapper causing errors

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.3.1, 404, modal

Is anyone else having an issue of late errors showing up in Magento 2.3.1? I stopped all extensions, and reverted back to the Magento Luma theme, and I'm getting this error:

```
misc.js:181 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

It also generates a 404 error in jquery.js. Has anyone else run into this issue? The error doesn't seem to show up until after modals-wrapper has finished loading in whatever it needs to.

You can see this happening here:

https://mccaskill.fmwebd.com/

Comment: Is this issues is solved, i am also getting this error with same version.